# Return Variable Referenced Before Assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, local

This is my code:

```
    def HTR(S, T):



        while S == 1:
            Z = 60
            if (S == 2):
                Z = 60 + (60*.5)
            elif (S == 3):
                Z = 60*2
            else:
                Z = 0


        return Z
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
        return Z
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Z' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: the line below return z is also part of the error message....         UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Z' referenced before assignment

Comment: Do you want to make that so, then?

Comment: What do you think `while S == 1` means?

Answer (score 1):

You must define `Z` prior to entering the `while loop`; otherwise, in case `S != 1`, the loop is not entered and `Z` is undefined when attempting to return it:

```
def HTR(S, T):

    Z = None            #<-- choose the value you wish to return is S != 1

    while S == 1:
        Z = 60                 #<-- Z is set to 60
        if (S == 2):               #<-- S already equals 1 at this point
            Z = 60 + (60*.5)
        elif (S == 3):             #<-- S already equals 1 at this point
            Z = 60*2
        else:
            Z = 0              #<-- then Z is always set to zero  
                               # this is probably not the behavior you are expecting!


    return Z
```

Comment: There's a lot more wrong with this code than just that.

Comment: Yes, I added comments in the code - it is rather unclear what the intent was

Answer (score 0):

```
def HTR(S, T):
    Z = -1  # init Z
    while S == 1:
        Z = 60
        if (S == 2):
            Z = 60 + (60*.5)
        elif (S == 3):
            Z = 60*2
        else:
            Z = 0

    return Z
```

In your code, the z won't be set if S is not 1. You need to give a initial value to Z. If S is not 1, -1 will be returned.